# Bootstrap Accordion with button, hide when expanded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-accordion

I'm looking for a solution for a bootstrap accordion with a button to expand the accordion, but I would like to hide this button when it is expanded.

My accordion headline is like the beginning of the text inside of the accordion, and if I have the button there it is disturbing the view.

How can I hide this button when the accordion is expanded, but visible again when the accordion is collapsed?

The problem here is, that when I click on the title, to close the accordion, then the button remains disappeared, and if I click on the title again, the accordion will expand, but the title will disappear as well. If Possible, I would like to keep the title as link.

```
a[data-toggle='collapse'].collapsed  {
   visibility: visible;
}

a[data-toggle='collapse']  {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/o93kwj80/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How will you close the accordion if you hide the title? I made a solution for you. If you click on the title, the title will be hidden and a close icon will show up. Then click on the close icon and the title will show up and accordion will be closed and close icon will be hidden.

```
a[data-toggle='collapse'].collapsed .title  {
  display: block;
}
a[data-toggle='collapse'].collapsed .close  {
  display: none;
}

a[data-toggle='collapse'] .title  {
  display: none;
}
a[data-toggle='collapse'] .close  {
  display: initial;
}
.close {
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

Please check the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o93kwj80/3/